# ckeditor debugging plugin image

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to add the doksoft_backup plugin to ckeditor. This is my second try at a plugin and like the first I can't seem to get buttons to appear. I have done the following:

- downloaded to the "plugins" directory.

[image: dir structure]

- Added the required code to my config.js ... the "extraPlugins" attribute.

  config.extraPlugins = 'doksoft_backup';

And a toolbar based on the docs.

```
config.toolbar = 'TrackingNotesToolBar';

    config.toolbar_TrackingNotesToolBar =
    [
        { name: 'source', items : [ 'Maximize','-','Source'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
        { name: 'images', itmes:    [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'backup', items : [ 'doksoft_backup_save','doksoft_backup_load' ] },

            '/',
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] }

    ];
```

The line that I'm trying to get moving is the one containing doksoft_backup_load and _save in it.  All the other toolbars listed here load just fine, but there's no save/load button for this plugin.

I tried using the autosave plugin as well. It actually *did function* and began saving content to keys in local storage on my browser, but like this one I never did get buttons to appear.

I am convinced there is something simple here. There are no JS console errors and I can't navigate to the png's that are supposed to be used.

Is there a trick I'm missing to getting buttons to display? Is there a debug mode for ckeditor that might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an error in the doksoft_backup installation instruction, you don't have to put following code in `config.js`:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'doksoft_backup';
```

Actually you can should put it on the Web page:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {extraPlugins: 'doksoft_backup'} );
```

This should make the two button show up.

Comment: Thanks George! You pushed me in the right direction. I'm seeing the buttons now.